# Autosizing not working on column with renderCell value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, autosize

Autosizing not working on the column where we use renderCell value

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/kind-brahmagupta-w87ynq?file=%2FDemo.js

```
{
        field: "rep",
        headerName: "Representative",
        renderCell: (params) => {
          if (!params.value) {
            return null;
          }
          return params.value + 1 + params.value;
        },
      },
```

just

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please refer https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/kind-brahmagupta-w87ynq?file=%2FDemo.js